# How long will npm registry hold my binaries / is there a retention policy?

Tags: node.js, npm

Anyone (with a npm account) can publish npm package with binaries inside. And that can be pretty huge.

I wonder is there is a limit to the number of packages you can submit (or a number of revisions, or a size per revision) , but i cannot find this information.
Is there a retention policy on npm (public) registry ?

Comment: This is not specific to binaries, but source code is never as big as the tiniest jpeg.

Comment: You might have better luck asking npm directly via twitter or their support email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no hard limit to either the number or size of binaries on npm.

In practice, the current npm command-line client begins to run into difficulties with binaries larger than 250MB, and in practice 99% of binaries on npm are smaller than 10MB, with 95% smaller than 5MB.

The number of revisions is also not limited, and versions will be kept indefinitely unless you actively unpublish them.

Attempts to explore the boundaries of these limits by creating infinitely many versions or exorbitantly large packages will be classified as abuse per the Code of Conduct at https://www.npmjs.com/policies/conduct. We'll ask you to unpublish packages that appear to exist just to mess with our limits, and ignoring our requests will probably result in us unpublishing the package.

Comment: npm is just great. Thx a lot for it.